# How to retrieve the nodes names of a vertica cluster using jdbc

Tags: vertica

Is there a way of retrieve the nodes names of a vertica cluster using jdbc?

in order to achieve a fault-tolerect connection strategy?

Can it retrieved from this retConnection Connection instance?

```
Connection retConnection = null;
.
.
.
retConnection = DriverManager.getConnection
                (
                        connectionString,
                        connectionProperties
                );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about...

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT node_name FROM v_catalog.nodes") ;
```